# Does Parse javascript sdk has any security issue as AppId and JavaScript key are open

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-applications, parse-platform

I'm very new to parse JavaScript SDK.

While developing an app using parse and JavaScript, **the app keys and client Id are open to the world**, as we can view JavaScript source.

Is there any risk of other person using them to create, unwanted objects in my table? If yes how can I avoid it?

Comment: see https://parse.com/docs/data#security

Comment: You can avoid it by creating cloud code functions that hide your parse object model, or by putting beforeSave triggers on your models in cloud code. But read the security guide linked by danh. It's important.